# ColdFusion Send page as it process it

Tags: coldfusion, railo

Is there a way in ColdFusion (or Railo for that matter) to begin sending the client the page as it processes it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: use the **cfflush** tag:

```
<cfoutput query="myQuery">
  #myQuery.myData#
  <cfflush>
</cfoutput>
```

http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf9/?getDoc=cfflush#cfflush

Comment: Just be warned that there are multiple places where cfflush can't be used. Also note that in some browsers (maybe just IE), you won't see anything until the browser thinks it has enough content to render. So I used to do #repeatString(" ",250)# before any use of cfflush.

Comment: IIS 7 + CF 9 seem to ignore cfflush too